# Pulling information from multiple workbooks in two different files

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm hoping there is way to do this. I'll provide a bit of background to see if its possible.

I work for a construction company that keeps track of jobs by numbers and each job has a series of phases. There are two folders that contain the excel sequence files for the jobs, "Sequence" for active jobs and "Old-Sequence" for closed jobs. Job excel files are titled "1376-1", "1376-2", "1376-2", with "1376" being the job number and "1" being the phase. Each individual job will have a series of lots (individual house) that can range from 1 to 10 or even more. There are 3 parts of a job that we track for shipment: EF, DM, HDW. When a lot ships each of these, we input the date under the corresponding column.

What I want to do is track all of the lots that have shipped HDW by corresponding job number and have an active total that's current. So for example, if I put job number 1376 in cell A1, I want cell B1 to count all of the lots that have a date in the HDW column of the excel files that have "1376" title and are located in both the "Sequence" and "Old-Sequence" folders.

We have about 100, so column 1 will have a series of job numbers to track. Does anyone know if this is a possibility?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds possible, but it's going to be tricky. Here's how I envision the VBA code working:

```
Iterate through all job numbers in your main worksheet. For each one:

    Iterate through all .xlsx files in your Sequence folder. For each one:
        If the filename includes the job number:
            Iterate through all rows, add up the cells in the HDW column with a date. 
            Add that number to the current job number's row in your main worksheet.
        If the filename does not include the job number, skip it.

    Iterate through all .xlsx files in your Old-Sequence folder. For each one:
        If the filename includes the job number:
            Iterate through all rows, add up the cells in the HDW column with a date. 
            Add that number to the current job number's row in your main worksheet.
        If the filename does not include the job number, skip it.
```

You're going to have to figure out how to do a few things...

1. Get a list of all Excel files in a directory. [This might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414106/get-list-of-excel-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)
2. Determine if a string exists in a filename. [This might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034532/excel-vba-function-that-checks-if-filename-contains-the-value)

Knowing how to reference multiple workbooks and how to deal with nested loops will be helpful too. Hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really new to this so I don't know really where to start. I just created a directory for both folders.

Comment: @clockwood: this is the most we can help you here, you got good suggestions. Writing the whole macro would mean we do your job. Learn coding or hire somebody to write it for you.

Comment: @clockwood: Do you have any coding experience? I'm new to VBA (and coding!) as well, so I might be able to help point you in the right direction depending on what you know already.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t. I thought maybe I could follow examples, similar to forming formulas, but I definitely don’t have enough understanding of coding. Thanks for your help though. I appreciate it

Comment: If you're interested in learning, VBA isn't a bad place to start, especially if you understand Excel at a basic level already. If you use Excel a lot, or want to move into a job where you do, understanding VBA at all is a huge leg up and will let you do all sorts of fun stuff. I learned the basics of VBA here: https://www.automateexcel.com/learn-vba-tutorial/

Comment: Perhaps the nicest thing about VBA and Excel is that you can record a macro of you doing something, then open the macro and see the code that was created. Because you know exactly what you did, it is relatively easy to learn how the code accomplishes what you did.